# Como saber que ip se conectou a um banco postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

A pergunta é a mesma do título:

Como saber que ip se conectou a um banco postgresql?

É que liberei o acesso externo e preciso ter um controle de onde vem os acessos.

Comment: Péssima ideia. Configure adequadamente seu arquivo `postgresql.conf` e `pg_hba.conf`. Avalie a configuração do log para identificar possíveis acessos indesejados.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a query abaixo. Nela haverá a coluna client_hostname que apresentará o endereço do client conectado baseado em um reverse DNS lookup. Ele só apresentará os clientes conectados através de ip.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';
```